# comma separated value to loop working with Hardcoded value but not with parameter value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle9i

My main problem is : i want to pass comma separated string in  to oracle 9i stored proc and inside it, i want to iterate through it and use each value in insert statements. Oracle 9i above version gives some internal function like regex_susbstr which can be used to implement this but with oracle 9i i am able to find one code which i pasted below. 
    That works fine when i used harcoded value of comma separated strings in stored proc, but when passed it though input parameter of stored proc, it consider that string as single value and just loop through it once and insert the full string in column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERTDOCUMENTDETAILS_BD
(
    BatchId  IN NUMBER,
    strDocumentIds IN varchar2
)
IS
  type table_varchar  is table of varchar2(32767);
  var_table_varchar  table_varchar;
begin
  var_table_varchar  := table_varchar(strDocumentIds);
  var_table_varchar  := table_varchar('004416979','004416987','004416988','004416989');

  for elem in 1 .. var_table_varchar.count loop
      Insert into documentdetails(DocumentID,BatchID,DocumentSRCGUID,Name,documentType,ExtractionStatus,InjectionStatus) 
      values(DocumentID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,BatchId,var_table_varchar(elem),'','',1,1);
  end loop;
end;
/
show errors;
```

Comment: You've already identified the problem in your question: "it consider that string as single value". Where is your input string coming from, and can that source provide a list of values instead of a single string value?

Comment: It is coming from .net code and i cannot pass collection as Oracle parameter from .net. But anyways i got the solution below from bob.
Thanks Alex :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table_varchar` type does not magically parse a string containing comma-separated values into separate substrings. You still have to do that.

Here's a nice little function which does the parsing for you. It uses the built-in system type `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A` instead of your table type, but the result is similar:

```
FUNCTION EXTRACT_TOKENS(p_string     IN VARCHAR2,
                        p_separators IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A
IS
  arrTokens DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
BEGIN
  WITH sel_string AS 
      (SELECT p_string AS fullstring FROM DUAL)
  SELECT SUBSTR(fullstring, beg + 1, end_p - beg - 1) AS token
    BULK COLLECT INTO arrTokens
    FROM (SELECT beg, LEAD(beg) OVER (ORDER BY beg) AS end_p, fullstring
            FROM (SELECT beg, fullstring
                    FROM (SELECT LEVEL beg, fullstring
                            FROM sel_string
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(fullstring))
                    WHERE INSTR(p_separators, SUBSTR(fullstring, beg, 1)) > 0
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT 0, fullstring FROM sel_string
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT LENGTH(fullstring) + 1, fullstring FROM sel_string))
    WHERE end_p IS NOT NULL AND
          end_p > beg + 1;

  RETURN arrTokens;
END EXTRACT_TOKENS;
```

You can use this by changing your procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERTDOCUMENTDETAILS_BD
(
    BatchId  IN NUMBER,
    strDocumentIds IN varchar2
)
IS
  var_table_varchar  DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A ;
begin
  var_table_varchar := EXTRACT_TOKENS(strDocumentIds, ',');

  for elem in 1 .. var_table_varchar.count loop
      Insert into documentdetails
        (DocumentID, BatchID, DocumentSRCGUID, Name, documentType, ExtractionStatus, InjectionStatus) 
      values
        (DocumentID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, BatchId, var_table_varchar(elem), ',' , 1, 1);
  end loop;
end SP_INSERTDOCUMENTDETAILS_BD;
```

Note that this still won't work because the field list on your `INSERT` statement has seven fields named while the `VALUES` clause only contains six values, but I'm sure you can fix that.

Comment: Thanks Bob, it worked perfectly fine. Really appreciate your help on this. I was stuck on this from last 4 days and was not able to find anything on google related to this problem.

Comment: However  I ran in to another issues where I am passing a long string in strDocumentIds input parameter, it gave exception :
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested.

When i am passing the length of string around 1200 characters it is working fine, but when i tried next batch with 6000 characters, it gave that error.

Also i have to use this SP to work for around 49000 character length. Any advise on that ?

Comment: Character strings in Oracle are limited to 4000 bytes, which means 4000 characters or less, depending on the character set used in your database. If you need to use longer strings you'll have to use CLOBs, which I have no experience with.

Comment: Thanks Bob, i replaced p_string from Varchar2 to CLOB in your Function EXTRACT_TOKENS and also did same for strDocumentIds  in  my Stored proc SP_INSERTDOCUMENTDETAILS_BD. And now it takes 32513 string length which is very huge as compared to what it was accepting earlier.